# Given a path between 2 vertices of a graph, there is only a finite number of vertices in the path?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, infinite-graphs

Let us have a weighted graph $G=(V,E)$ with set of vertices $V$ and set of edges $E$, with a function $E\to V\times V$, a weight function $w:E\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ etc.
Take the topological realization $|G|$, where if $e\in E$, then $length(e):=w(e)$, and two vertices $v,v'\in V$ such that there is a path $P\subset|G|$ (i.e. homeomorphic to a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$) joining them. Then I think $V\bigcap P$ should be finite. Why?

For example, it seems to me I could not take as a graph having topological realization the interval $[0,1]$ the one given by vertices $V=\{1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...,1/n,...,0\}$ and edges connecting them with the natural weight, since there is not an edge connecting $0$ with any other vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an open covering of $|G|$ as follows: take the the interior of each edge (that is to say, the edges without their end points) and a small neighbourhood around each vertex (that contains at most a quarter of each adjoining edge). This is an open covering, and since $P$ is compact, it should be covered by finitely many of these open sets. Since each vertex is included in a unique open set in this covering, there can only by finitely many vertices on $P$.

Comment: @iago, you should be advised that if your edge lengths vary (as per your previous comment), then this argument does not hold, because a point plus a quarter of each of its adjacent edges may not be a neighbourhood (to be precise, it is a neighbourhood if and only if the infimum of the edge lengths leading into the point is greater than 0).

Comment: But the infimum of the edge lengths leading into the point is greater than 0 since only there are two edges attaching the point.

Answer (score 1):

*By definition* a path between two vertices has only finitely many vertices in it, even if the *graph* the path exists in is infinite.

For a *drawing* of a graph (that is, your "topological realization") one usually assumes that the set of points that represents vertices is discrete.

If there's a sequence of vertex points that converge towards a different vertex, then this convergence is *not a graph-theoretic property*, but rather a defect of the *drawing*. (In other words, the drawing is then not homeomorphic to the *abstract* realization of the graph as a gluing-together of single points for vertices and copies of $[0,1]$ for edges).

Comment: You are right. I should have told that my graphs are weighted, so the length of the topological realization of an edge is its weight by definition.

Comment: @iago: But that doesn't in itself justify placing a vertex at a point that is a limit point of other vertices.With your convention, the set of vertex points may need to _have_ limit points, but those limits should not be vertices themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The paths in an infinite graph are the finite paths, the rays, and the double rays. If you think of the integers as the vertices of a graph $Z$ whose edges are $\{n,n+1\}$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$, the subgraph $N$ induced by the natural numbers is a ray, and the whole graph is a double ray. In an arbitrary infinite graph the rays are the subgraphs isomorphic to $Z$, and the double rays are the subgraphs isomorphic to $N$. Note that only the finite paths have a vertex at each end.

In a topological realization the finite paths are homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, the rays to $[0,\to)$, and the double rays to $\Bbb R$.